# How to enable and disable items in the menu contribution?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am trying to use a property tester on a menu contribution that I have done for my eclipse plugin.

Basically I added a new menu in the main menu bar (by extending menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu and adding a menu). I then added my commands in there with the correct handlers. 
Everything works as expected.

My only problem is that I am not able to decide when to have them active. 
I am trying to use the activeWhen for my handlers. i want them to be active when there is certain data on a server.

I tried using a property tester but it does not get called everytime. It only gets called when you select a different view.

What is the correct way of doing this?

EDIT: here is the code I am using 
http://pastebin.com/TGtZaBtM

My property tester runs because I print out stuff when it does. 
The only problem is that it does not run every time the menu is opened.
I would like it to run every time so that I can check if a user is logged in or not.

Comment: Update your post with relevant `plugin.xml` content and related code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably answering late...

Anyway to do that, I always define a `sourceProvider` and some `variable` using the `org.eclipse.ui.services` extension point:

As example for a pause action somewhere in a toolbar, here is the piece of code of the source provider and its definition in the plugins.xml:

```
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.services">
      <sourceProvider
            provider="DataCollectionSourceProvider">
         <variable
               name="Pause"
               priorityLevel="workbench">
         </variable>
      </sourceProvider>
  </extension>
```

source provider:

```
public class DataCollectionSourceProvider extends AbstractSourceProvider {

    public final static String ID        = "DataCollectionSourceProvider";
    public final static String ID_PAUSED = "Pause";
    public final static String VAL_TRUE  = "TRUE";
    public final static String VAL_FALSE = "FALSE";

    /**
     * @return the instance of this source provider in this workbench
     */
    public static DataCollectionSourceProvider getInstance() {
        ISourceProviderService sourceProviderService = ISourceProviderService)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ISourceProviderService.class);
        DataCollectionSourceProvider dcProvider = (DataCollectionSourceProvider)sourceProviderService.getSourceProvider(ID);
        return dcProvider;
    }


    private boolean paused = false;

    public DataCollectionSourceProvider() {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public Map<?, ?> getCurrentState() {
        String value = null;
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(2);

        // fake variable (my id)
        map.put(ID, VAL_TRUE);

        // paused state
        value = paused ? VAL_TRUE : VAL_FALSE;
        map.put(ID_PAUSED, value);

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getProvidedSourceNames() {
        return new String[] { ID, ID_PAUSED };
    }

    public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
        this.paused = paused;
        String value = paused ? VAL_TRUE : VAL_FALSE;
        fireSourceChanged(ISources.WORKBENCH, ID_PAUSED, value);
    }
}
```

Then on your `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` contribution, add the enableWhen by using the variable from its defined id:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            commandId="__your_command_id__">
         <class
               class="__your_handler_class__">
         </class>
         <enabledWhen>
            <with
                  variable="Pause">
               <equals
                     value="FALSE">
               </equals>
            </with>
         </enabledWhen>
      </handler>
</extension>
```

At last, if you want to update the handler/action state, you just have to call the following piece of code somewhere in your code

```
DataCollectionSourceProvider.getInstance().setPause(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance: You are using 'activeWhen' in your handler. You can probably try using '[enabledWhen](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_handlers.html&cp=2_1_1_153&anchor=e.enabledWhen)' in the XML

You can also look into overriding [isEnabled()](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/commands/AbstractHandler.html#isEnabled%28%29) in your Handler. This will work, when your plugin is activated. Look into the docs for more information.